# PHP Make an $ function to an link with an get function

Tags: php, wordpress, user-profile

```
global $userpro;
$user_id=get_the_author_ID(); 
echo $userpro->permalink( get_the_author_meta('ID'));
echo get_avatar( $user_id, 15 );
echo userpro_profile_data('display_name', $user_id, $profile_url);
```

with this code i get the user profile link and a username
but i want to have the username as link to the user profile.
so how i add the link to the user name?

If you have an question feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have the link `$userpro->permalink( get_the_author_meta('ID'));` and the text.

Read [HTML a tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

Comment: Hey, i tried some things like
 echo "<a href=$userpro->permalink( get_the_author_meta('ID'));</a>"
But i dont find the right function :-/

Comment: You don't need any function, if you have both information: link and text. `<a href="$link">$text</a>`

Comment: but a href=$userpro->permalink( get_the_author_meta('ID'));</a> dont work

Comment: `$userpro->permalink( get_the_author_meta('ID'));` is only the link! You need to replace $link and $text from my previous comment with your variables. Try to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003116/changing-author-link-on-posts-in-wordpress

Comment: <a href="$userpro->permalink( get_the_author_meta('ID'));">$user_id=get_the_author_ID();</a>
don't work

Comment: `$user_id=get_the_author_ID();` is not a variable, is an assignment.  You said you got "the user profile link and a username". What's your username variable?

Comment: echo userpro_profile_data('display_name', $user_id, $profile_url);

Comment: <a href=<?php echo $userpro->permalink( get_the_author_meta('ID') ); ?>><?php echo $user_id=get_the_author_meta('display_name');?></a>

Now i have to do it clickable ... :) :-/